# How can i configure ffmpeg with both openssl and h264

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I use this to configure ffmpeg:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-yasm --enable-openssl --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --prefix=/mnt/newdatadrive/apps/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-master
```

But it returned a error:

> OpenSSL <3.0.0 is incompatible with the gpl

But i need both of them, how to resolve this?

Comment: Add `--enable-nonfree`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that openSSL 3.0 is not compatible with GPL 2.0. My guess is that you should try using GPL 3.0 or higher instead. The issue seems to be that the apache license is not compatible with GPL 2.0.

You can try using `--enable-gpl` with `--enable-version3` build params which should help.

You can try using `--enable-nonfree` as well. Not sure if this is useful though

You should consider looking into `./configure --help` for more details on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use.

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-yasm --enable-openssl --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --prefix=/mnt/newdatadrive/apps/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-master
```